# Laravel Get all related data from models

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 many to many relationships and trying to get all related data.
User model:

```
public function roles()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role_pivot', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Role model:

```
public function rolepermissions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\RolePermission', 'role_permissions_connect', 'role_id', 'role_perm_id');
}
```

I'm making policies and want to get all values from my  `rolepermissions`.

my policy:

```
public function createrole(User $user)
{
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        foreach ($role->rolepermissions as $permission) {
            return $permission->permission_name;
        }
    }
}
```

It only returns only one result, but i want to get all related data from role permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning  `$permission->permission_name`
so the `return` forces the function to stop executing. You're better off returning an array.

```
 $roles = [];
 foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
      foreach ($role->rolepermissions as $permission) {
        $roles[] = $permission->permission_name;
      }
    }
}
return $roles;
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as a function hits `return`, it stops to execute and returns the result. It's different than for example `yield return` in C# where you can actually return multiple values.

Anyways, You might want to add everything to an array and then use your array to execute actions, like this:

```
public function createrole(User $user) {
    $array = [];
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        foreach ($role->rolepermissions as $permission) {
            array_push($array, $permission);
        }
    }

    dd($array); //add this line if you want to see your array's items

    foreach($item in $array){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Now that we're doing best practices anyways, you can also do this:

```
foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    foreach ($role->rolepermissions as $key => $permission) {
        $array[$key] = $permission;
    }
}
```

Which is performance-wise probably more efficient.

Comment: beat me too it as i was typing :-)

Comment: @rchatburn haha you need to be fast here ;-)